# coordinate frame, computation of coefficients

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, frenet-frame

Let $\mathbf{e_j}$ be a local coordinate frame on the manifold $M$.

How do I compute/obtain the coefficients $A_j^k$ so that
$$\mathbf{e_j} (v^i) = A_j^k \partial_k (v^i)= A^k_j \frac{\partial v^i}{\partial x^k}$$.

In other words
how do I obtain the real numbers $A_j^k$ so that
$$\mathbf{e_j} = A_j^k \partial_k$$?

What is the formula for these numbers?

Comment: The last formula you have written is actually the one which gives the relationship between the two local frames. You can get $A_j^k$ from that.

Comment: Usually you have $\partial_i$'s first, and you build new frame $e_i$'s in terms of those $\partial_i$'s.

Comment: And are the $A_j^k$'s uniquely determined?Is $A_j^k$ a regular matrix then?